# Django - relational constraint (constraint on user's groups)

Tags: django, django-models

In my django - app I setup permissions for different `facilities` with the following groups:

```
ADMIN_<facility>
USER_<facility>
```

Where admin has all the rights that user has and some more.

I would like to constraint that a user that has the group `ADMIN_facility1` will never be added to group `USER_facility1`. My approach:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
...
    @property
    def admin_facilities(self):
        [g.name for g in self.groups.filter(name__startswith="ADMIN_")]

    @property
    def user_facilities(self):
        [g.name for g in self.groups.filter(name__startswith="USER_")]

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        for user_fac in self.user_facilities:
            if user_fac in self.admin_facilities:
                # remove the user facility
                self.groups.remove(
                    self.groups.get(name="USER_{}".format(user_fac)
                )
        super(MyUser, self).save(**kwargs)
...
```

This approach does not work, as the groups are not there yet during the call of the save function.

**Question:** How do I constraint that a user who is in a `ADMIN_<facility>` group can never be added to the according `USER_<facility>` group?

Answer (score 0):

You could send the save call to the beginning, like this:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    super(MyUser, self).save(**kwargs)
    for user_fac in self.user_facilities:
        if user_fac in self.admin_facilities:
            # remove the user facility
            self.groups.remove(
                self.groups.get(name="USER_{}".format(user_fac)
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

`M2M field` have totally different order of getting saved.

User instance must be saved before populating M2M data(Think about the database).
I think what you Need is [m2m_changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) signal.

And Write that similar code on `post_add` i think.